# Tesseract-ocr is not working properly after integrating with alfresco 5.0.d

Tags: java, ocr, alfresco, tesseract, alfresco-share

I have integrated Tesseract-ocr in Alfresco 5.0.d, My requirement is to convert PDF file data in to text format.

And Its working fine for small sized files.

But if i will upload larger size files, say more than 50 MB,

In that case its giving below Exception, and whole pdf file is not get converted in to text file.
Only some starting pages are getting converted to text format.

Please refer the below logs

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
```

Does Anyone have faced the same issue, Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can anyone please help me to resolve this, it's really on high priority

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to increase the content transformation size of pdf to text 
in alfresco-global.properties file

you can give size for transformation using these properties

if you are using OOoDirect

`content.transformer.complex.OpenOffice.Pdf2swf.extensions.doc.swf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=5120  content.transformer.complex.OpenOffice.Pdf2swf.extensions.docx.swf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=5120`

if you are using OOoJodConverter

```
content.transformer.complex.JodConverter.Pdf2swf.extensions.doc.swf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=5120
content.transformer.complex.OpenOffice.Pdf2swf.extensions.docx.swf.maxSourceSizeKBytes=5120
```

refer this community question 
https://community.alfresco.com/thread/211670-changing-transformation-limits-version-5b

https://community.alfresco.com/thread/203406-how-to-config-alfresco-documents-preview-size-limit-on-42d

https://injustfiveminutes.wordpress.com/2012/11/28/docx-pptx-document-preview-fails-on-alfresco-4-2-c/

Comment: you can change maxSourceSizeKBytes values.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit surprised. Alfresco already includes PDFBox who is in charge of doing PDF --> TXT conversion. And so you don't need to use Tesseract.
Even your trace seems a bit weird. To see what's going on with the transformers, set `log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.TransformerDebug` and `log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.content.transform` equals 
to `DEBUG`.

Comment: Actually the PDF contains Scanned images, and i have to use Tesseract... But i am not getting why its giving Read Time out Error. Can you help me to resolve that Error, or it it possible to increase that time out period

Comment: Hi, are you using this module (https://github.com/bchevallereau/alfresco-tesseract). It's one that i developped myself.

Comment: I have downloaded it from following link, https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki  and using same

Comment: Do you have any other approach to do the same, If possible, please give me some steps. I am a bit new to alfresco, so not having much idea. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you please tell some more about this, I am still not able to fix the issue. Its not working for large size files...

Comment: Try to use my module: https://github.com/bchevallereau/alfresco-tesseract